# No Fatal error thrown when PHP is both out of time and memory. When it should

Tags: php, apache, memory, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I have been looking into improving the stability of our application; allowing it to recover from fatal errors. The recovery method is to catch fatal errors in the PHP registered shutdown function `register_shutdown_function()` using the line:

```
$error = error_get_last();
```

this will retrieve the fatal error eg. <kbd>out of memory</kbd>, <kbd>time out exceeded</kbd>, <kbd>uncaught exceptions</kbd>, <kbd>undefined functions</kbd>, etc.

The error can then be logged to our error logger and the user redirected to a safe error page where they can navigate to another page. This all works fine catching <kbd>out of memory</kbd> and <kbd>time out errors</kbd> except for the following scenario :

*nb: using CodeIgnitor framework*

```
    ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 10);

    $this->db->query('select * from massive_table');
```

Now if the table massive_table has say for example 9 million rows, it will take a while to grab all the rows into PHP. However the application crashes without reporting an error.

The issue only appears when the results of query would be bigger than the memory limit and it has exceeded the PHP `max_execution_time`.

The process is as follows :

Once the query has been parsed and sent to through the MySQL driver, I can see it running in the MySQL processes list. This will obviously take a while to select 9 million rows, before it returns the PHP time out value of 10 seconds is exceeded. I would now expect PHP to throw the `max_execution_time` reached fatal error, however PHP still seems to wait past the 10 seconds. At some short time after the code will crash without reporting a fatal error.

If the `max_execution_time` is high enough for it return then I will get an <kbd>out of memory</kbd> fatal error

If the `memory_limit` is high enough but the time exceeded then I will correctly get a `max_execution_time` reached fatal error.

The issue is only when both conditions are reached which only seems to manifest when PHP is communicating with MySQL.

There is nothing added to the Apache error log either.

Another side effect that leads me to think that it might be bug in PHP/ Apache is that in the specific scenario the 9 million rows (or how many it gets up to before crashing), are left in memory are are not cleared out. I need to restart Apache to clear my RAM. I only discovered this when my computer ground to a halt and noticed all 16GB of my RAM had been allocation and wasn't getting cleared. So it seems there could be a memory leak here.

Comment: If it is of any use... I wouldn't expect PHP to timeout while waiting on a MySQL query to run. PHP is most likely in a wait state and checking the time. Then, when MySQL begins a response, it suddenly kicks in and starts checking the time again. Of course, it will most likely notice that the memory reserve request from the database connection exceeds available memory before it notices that the time has expired.

Comment: I like the fact that this is a well written, detailed question ... I don't like the fact that I have absolutely no idea :|

Comment: @kainaw, interesting, however then surely that should throw out of memory error instead then

Comment: haha @CD001, this made me chuckle. Ye it has got me stumped, it is an odd one. What rung the alarm bells was the fact that memory on my PC wasn't getting flushed.

Comment: I ran my own tests. For reference, I am on Fedora 20 with MariaDB. Still, I think this may be relevant. Using a standard query, I get what appears to be a segmentation fault. No error. The script just dies. But, if I run they query in async mode, I get a normal PHP timeout. Maybe you can run your query in async mode. I'd also use the stream mode to pull results one at a time instead of waiting for the whole batch.

Comment: how are you running the query in async mode, that a connection variable ? A quick google has not brought anything up for this. thanks

Comment: To me it seems like error in the mysql driver. It constructs return array in memory when the timeout kicks in. I suppose it handles this situation incorrectly. Do you see errors in apache error log? The time spent to query mysql server is not counted into php's run time.

Comment: nope nothing added to the Apache error log :/ I will add that to the original post

Comment: @MadDokMike I use mysqli by default. It has MYSQLI_ASYNC as a query option. However, it isn't really part of mysqli. It is part of the MySQL native driver, which is an option for both mysqli and PDO. It looks like you are using PDO, which I rarely use.

Comment: Thanks @kainaw, I look into trying it out by switching our driver, we are actually using the oldest driver; plain mysql (I know its old, however...the joys of maintaining legacy code). In CodeIgnitor I believe it is relatively easy to switch drivers.